# Android settext() from another class(not an activity) not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a main Activity where I have a layout inflated.
I have a text view (textView)in the activity which I want to update from another class named 'Util.java' (this class does not extend anything, it is just a library class) where I have written methods common to the project for re usability).

Now on receiving a broadcast I update the text of the 'textView' by calling the method in Util.java using 'Util.setLoadingText(R.string.loadingText_creating_device);'

```
 public static void setLoadingText(int resId) {
    if (!Util.isNull(loadingText)) {
        Log.d(Util.TAG, LOG_LABEL + "SET TEXT CALLED:SHOW LOADING SCREEN" );
        loadingText.setText(resId);

    }
}
```

before calling the above method, I am calling 'Util.init(this)' in the onCreate of the main activity.below is the code for

```
 public static void init(Activity activity) {
    activity.setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);
    Log.d(Util.TAG, LOG_LABEL + "INIT CALLED:SHOW LOADING SCREEN" );
    loadingText = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.loadingScreenTextView);
}
```

There are no compilation errors, but the

```
  loadingText.setText(resId);
```

does not update the text.
Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: why not pass the view to the non activity class !

Comment: @twntee: I have 3 classes here, 1)Util.java where the settext methos is present 2)MainActivity 3)Broadcastreceiver.java which calls the settext methos in the Util.java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't update things on the ui thread from anywhere but the ui thread, you need to use this .Where mAct is the main activity but you have to pass it in a parameter to the other class so it has access to it because it can't be a static reference

```
public static void updateText(Activity act, resID)
{

 loadingText = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.loadingScreenTextView);
          act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                {
                     public void run() 
                     {
                       loadingText.setText(resID);

                     }

                });
}
```

Comment: I added this to my code, but now the code inside mAct.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() is not being compiled, any idea?

Comment: what do you mean not being compiled? is it giving errors and you can't export/load the app? or is it not executing

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say that the code inside runOnUiThread is not being executed. No compilation errors

Comment: what function are you calling in the `run()`

Comment: MainActivity.functionToUpdateTV("new text"); , but my setText method is in Util.java, not in the main Activity.

Comment: that was just an example function, not something that does anything, I'll update my answer to reflect what I think your code should look like

Comment: Earlier that was what I did, but as I said the code inside activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    loadingText.setText(resId);
                }
            }); does not get executed :(

Comment: the problem might be that `activity` is not the currently displayed activity or the `textview`is not the one being displayed, beyond that I don't know. If you are sure that the code should be executed then there is no reason for it not to execute, maybe put a log print in to see if it is executing and not doing what you want or just not executing

Comment: I have put a debug point and found that the code was not being executed. will update you , thanks a lot for you time .

Answer (score 1):

try to implement interface. In class `Util.java` write:

```
public interface onSomeEventListener {
    public void someEvent(String s);
}

onSomeEventListener someEventListener;
```

and:

```
someEventListener.someEvent("Test text to...");
```

in Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements onSomeEventListener{
```

and:

```
@Override
public void someEvent(String s) {
    loadingText.setText(resId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From non activity class

```
//call class name
  VerifyMobile Sms = new VerifyMobile();
                    Sms.recivedSms(s);
```

from activity class VerifyMobile.java

```
static EditText verify_numbertext;

verify_numbertext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.verify_numbertext);
```

Funcation of set text in editText

```
public static void recivedSms(String message) 
     {
         verify_numbertext.setText(message);

     }
```